# How to change Collation to utf8_bin in one go

Tags: mysql, database-design, utf-8, collation

I have set up the Collation of all my database tables as `latin1_swedish_ci` and now I realise that I should use `utf8_bin` or `utf8_general_ci`.

How can I change the Collation in the tables to `utf8_bin` or `utf8_general_ci` in one go? Can I use a query or something?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You'll simply need to run an ALTER on each of the tables as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

If you also need to update the existing character encoding (unlikely by the sounds of things), you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also update the database collation with:

```
ALTER DATABASE  `DATABASE_NAME` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Doing this seems to have set the collate on all the tables in the schema.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the collation of a table with `ALTER TABLE`:

```
alter table table_name collate=utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways. First one worked for me. From the terminal  (Just remember to backup before.)

```
mysql --database=dbname -B -N -e "SHOW TABLES"  | awk '{print "ALTER TABLE", $1, "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;"}' | mysql --database=dbname &
```

Source: [Commandlineinfu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1575/convert-all-mysql-tables-and-fields-to-utf8)

From MySQL
you will have to use the Concat command

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', tbl.`TABLE_SCHEMA`, '`.`', tbl.`TABLE_NAME`, '` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;') FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` tbl WHERE tbl.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'dbname'
```