# ä ö character encoding, in PHP, Zend MySQL- application

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character

Problem:

When I retrieve values from MySQL table to my PHP Zend Framework-application, the characters ä and ö are returned from the database to my browser like this �.

Any ideas where the problem might occur? I have tried setting some properties to UTF-8, but still this occurs...I think I have still missed something.

Could you give some solutions how I can get rid of this for sure? What configs I need to set etc.

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you post your `Zend_DB` factory code? Are you sure that isn't an escape problem? Did you set the Chareset HTTP header?

Comment: What is the collation of the table this data is being pulled from? Make sure you look at the table and not the database, because tables can easily have a different collation than the database.

Comment: My application is in the very beginning at the moment and my database code is very minimal and handles only the setup of the connection so far, but I will post the code I use (P.S. I'm a beginner so bear with me ;D)

Comment: require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . "/models/Properties.php");

class Db
{
 
 public static function conn()
 {
  $connProp = Properties::getProperties("database.properties");
  
  $connParams = array("host" => $connProp['host'],
            "port" => $connProp['port'],
            "username" => $connProp['username'],
            "password" => $connProp['password'],
            "dbname" => $connProp['dbname']);
  
  $db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($connParams);
  return $db;
 }
 
}

Comment: The collation was latin1_swedish_ci as suspected below :) Thanx everyone

Comment: Then please mark an answer correct / upvote the ones that helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When characters of the wrong encoding are read to the browser, they come up as � or ?. There is an encoding mismatch somewhere:

- In your browser
- In the database table collation
- In the HTML charset

Those characters would work in Unicode UTF-8, so you should verify that your DB table collation is `utf8_bin` or similar, as, if you want to store everything in UTF-8 Swedish, you might use `utf8_swedish_ci`

In your browser, ensure that your content encoding is set to auto-detect.

To create a UTF-8 / utf8_bin table in MySQL, here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE `sample` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

To ALTER an existing table to use UTF-8, use the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784168/how-to-change-collation-to-utf8-bin-in-one-go) has a good explanation of whether or not to use `CONVERT TO CHRACTER SET utf8`

Note `CHARSET` and `COLLATE` must both be set, otherwise you will automatically get `COLLATE=utf8_general_ci`

For HTML, charset can be set using:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I will see which one helps and post the results ;)

Comment: A common problem is for the table charset and collation to be in cp1252 (latin1) and latin1_general_ci

Answer (score 1):

I woudl suggest you have a look into your "website encoding" set in the browser.

If the website does not supply a encoding and your mysql/php is handling it "correctly" this could happen (e.g. its set to "western 1252" but requires utf8/unicode)

In Firefox you can see the encoding via view -> encoding (or similar)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to properly set your encoding to UTF-8. Here are the basic steps for a minimal working solution :

1. Make sure your [DB connection uses UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584676/how-to-make-pdo-run-set-names-utf8-each-time-i-connect-in-zendframework)
2. Make sure your HTTP content-type is set to UTF-8 (Ex: `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` (also, you may specify the encoding [for your document](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations))
3. Save your file as UTF-8. In Windows, files are saved as CP-1251, which means that special accented chars are not treated as UTF-8 encoded bytes (thus throw off what is being output to the browser. You have to explicitly set your encoding when saving your files. In Linux/Mac, this is not a problem as UTF-8 is used by default.
4. Make sure your `php.ini` does not override the encoding. If you have foreign `.htaccess` files, check that they do not so either.

If you correctly handle UTF-8, you won't require `utf8_encode`/`utf8_decode`, `htmlentities` etc. and will be able to properly output accented characters without special treatement.

**Note** : some locales are not handled by UTF-8, notably [Thaï](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917714/file-get-contents-not-working-with-utf8/4917724#4917724).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding **Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql** make sure that your constructor is using **UTF-8**, like this:

```
$your_pdo = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
                'host'     => DATABASE_HOST,
                'username' => DATABASE_USERNAME,
                'password' => DATABASE_PASSWORD,
                'dbname'   => DATABASE_DBNAME,
                'options'  => array( 'charset' => 'utf8' )
        ) );
```

And before using data in **HTML** escape it:

```
return htmlspecialchars( $string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
```

Check out all other answers for Content-Type, file encoding and more.